# grep() with multiple column names in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, match

I have a `data.frame` with 5786 columns. I'd like to find the column locations using the header names without searching through `colnames()` of the `data.frame`.

I thought using `grep()` would work but I'm finding that giving it multiple patterns at once doesn't jive. So far, I thought of something like this, which doesn't work:

```
    grep(c("NameA", "NameB", "NameC"), colnames(df))
```

Is there an easier way to do this? Maybe using the `which()` function?

Comment: `match()` maybe?

Comment: does grep("NameA|NameB|NameC", colnames(df)) do what you need?

Comment: As @joran mentioned try `match(colnames(df), c("NameA", "NameB", "NameC"))`

Comment: @MKR and @joran, the `match()` statement works but it gives me an output of NAs for where this isn't true (i.e, the column names don't match). How can I get just a print out of the column number that matches the name?

Comment: @stat123 You have to filter is using  `is.na()` condition. I posted it as answer. Have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by `@joran`, the complete answer can be achieved using `match`. The result of `match` should be filtered for `!is.na()` condition.

```
# Toy data frame
df <- data.frame(NameA = 1:5,
                 NameB = LETTERS[1:5],
                 NameC = letters[1:5],
                 NameD = letters[6:10])

# Find matched columns
which(!is.na(match(colnames(df), c("NameD", "NameB", "NameA"))))

#[1] 1 2 4
```

Comment: when I run this as you did, I get as an answer for `col[!is.na(col)]` 1,2,3, rather than 116, 561, and 1007, which are the corresponding column locations within the `data.frame` for NameA, NameB, and NameC.

Comment: Actually just got it! `which(!is.na(col))` Thanks @MKR!!

Comment: @stat123 Actually, I posted in hurry. You can simply use it as `which(!is.na(match(colnames(df), c("NameD", "NameB", "NameA"))))`