# How to check for existence of a set of columns in large dataframes?

Tags: r, dataframe, match, grepl

I am constructing repeated cross-sectional (a panel) from multiple years of survey data. The survey data for each year is published as a separate dataframe with inconsistencies in variable names (column names) and sometimes variables are missing entirely. There are 450 columns so manual previewing is out of the question. As such, I want to search each dataframe to check for the existence of a list of variables of interest.

I first tried `dplyr::select()` but this is insufficient because it walks through the column names in order and only produces a warning for the first column name that can't be found in the dataframe when there may be in fact mutliple:

```
df <- data.frame(c1 = 1:5,
                  c2 = letters[1:5],
                  c3 = letters[1:5],
                  c4 = letters[1:5],
                  c5 = letters[1:5],
                  c6 = letters[1:5])
> 
> select(df, c(c1, c2, c7, c10, c11))
Error in `select()`:
! Can't subset columns that don't exist.
✖ Column `c7` doesn't exist.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

The answer to this similar question ([grep() with multiple column names in data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50647011/grep-with-multiple-column-names-in-data-frame?newreg=63d1d79b4c504a65976efcec952f1005)) I also find unsatisfactory.

```
which(!is.na(match(colnames(df), c("c1", "c2", "c7", "c10", "c11"))))
[1] 1 2
```

The position of the matching column names is returned (not the names) but it is the non-matching column names which are the most important for us to know, the real problem has 10 or more variables of interest so a human friendly output is important.

Does anyone know of a better way? Perhaps a function that would produce a table of matches (`TRUE`/`FALSE`) for each supplied column name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `%in%` with `!` to get a logical vector of columns that are *not* present in the data set:

```r
cols <- c("c1", "c2", "c7", "c10", "c11")
!cols %in% colnames(df)
#[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Or with `setdiff` to get the names:

```r
setdiff(cols, colnames(df))
#[1] "c7"  "c10" "c11"
```

And to select directly the columns in the data.frame without error messages, use `any_of`:

```r
library(dplyr)
select(df, any_of(cols))
#   c1 c2
# 1  1  a
# 2  2  b
# 3  3  c
# 4  4  d
# 5  5  e
```

Comment: Thanks, both are useful. Nevertheless using cols %in%, because there are 13 variables I have to do some manual mapping in my head between the FALSE results and order of column names supplied. I combined it with a tibble and it makes for a readable output: 'tibble(cols, cols %in% colnames(df))'

Comment: 'setdiff' is a simple and elegant solution for the way I'm working. (Finding those missing variables based on a list of expected column names in each years df and attempting to select a maximum set of variables which are present in all dataframes).

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `outer` approach. Use both a names vector of variables of interest as well as a named list of your data frames.

```
v <- c('X1', 'X3', 'X7', 'X10', 'X11') |> setNames(nm=_)

f <- \(x, y) x %in% names(y)
t(outer(v, mget(ls(pattern='^df\\d$')), Vectorize(f)))
#       X1    X3    X7  X10   X11
# df1 TRUE  TRUE  TRUE TRUE FALSE
# df2 TRUE FALSE  TRUE TRUE FALSE
# df3 TRUE  TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE
```

Instead of `mget(ls(.))` you can also hard-code the list, using

```
list(df1=df1, df2=df2, df3=df3)
```

*Explanation:* We want to know if the statement `v %in% names(df)` is true, and that for each of multiple data frames. What's needed is kind of a double for-loop approach, with the outer looping over the data frames and the inner over `v`. However we can use `outer`, which can be used for such problems, of two vectors X and Y it iterates each element of Y over each element of X and throws a matrix. We just have to `Vectorize` the statement.

### Edit

You might want to apply a consistent logic to variable naming in your set of data frames. For instance, three characters to abbreviate the meaning (`abbreviate('ethnicity', 3)` will help), but more importantly followed by two digits (or any number, as long as globally consistent) that carry congruent meaning. This would allow you to use `endsWith`.

```
ptt <- sprintf('%02d', c(1, 3, 7, 10, 11)) |> setNames(nm=_)
```

*Note:* The `sprintf('%02d', .)` conveniently fills up to two digits with a leading zero, `%02d`, and the `_` is the base placeholder what was piped into `setNames`, i.e. output names are identical to content of each element (we want it for the matrix to be well displayed):

```
ptt
#   01   03   07   10   11 
# "01" "03" "07" "10" "11" 

f <- \(x, y) any(endsWith(names(x), y))
```

Adapted `outer` solution:

```
outer(mget(ls(pattern='^df[4-6]$')), ptt, Vectorize(f))
#       01    03    07   10    11
# df4 TRUE  TRUE  TRUE TRUE FALSE
# df5 TRUE FALSE  TRUE TRUE FALSE
# df6 TRUE  TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE
```

Again, the search pattern `'^df[4-6]$'` looks for df4, df5, and df6; but instead of the `mget(.)` you can use a named list `list(df4=df4, df5=df5, df6=df6)`, but `mget` is neat.

---

*Data:*

```
df1 <- df2 <- df3 <- data.frame(matrix(,2, 10))

df2$X3  <- NULL
df3$X2  <- df3$X7  <- NULL


df4 <- df5 <- df6 <- data.frame(matrix(,2, 10))

names(df4) <- paste0('eth', sprintf('%02d', seq_along(df4)))
names(df5) <- paste0('rgn', sprintf('%02d', seq_along(df5)))
names(df6) <- paste0('inc', sprintf('%02d', seq_along(df6)))


df5[3] <- NULL
df6[2] <- df6[7]  <- NULL
```

Comment: This is impressively succinct but I'm too much of an amateur to fully understand what's going on here.

Comment: @humans-meet-quantities Explanation added, does it make sense so?

Comment: It makes more sense now, I appreciate the explanation. This solution goes a step further than my problem by giving the output for all df's together. Because there are slight differences in the column names between the datasets (updates to variable definitions), I'm approaching the problem on a df by df basis. I'd like to get better at applying loops so thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @humans-meet-quantities In what way do the names differ across the data frames? Maybe there is a solution.

Comment: Usually the fist few characters of the column name is the same like for ethnicity it would be eth01, ethn02 etc with the values being largely the same. I have solved my version of this problem using setdiff() on a df by df basis but I admire your search for the perfect solution.

Comment: @humans-meet-quantities Try `endsWith`, please see edit.

Answer (score 0):

Also we can use the below code to create the vectors `vars_in` and `vars_notin`
Once we know the variables that exists then we can use that vector `vars_in` with all_of() in select()

```r
cols <- c("c10", "c2", "c7", "c1", "c11")

vars_in <- cols[which(!is.na(match(cols,colnames(df))))]
[1] "c2" "c1"

vars_notin <- cols[which(is.na(match(cols,colnames(df))))]
[1] "c10" "c7"  "c11"

select(df, all_of(vars_in))

# output

  c2 c1
1  a  1
2  b  2
3  c  3
4  d  4
5  e  5
```